# Failed to retrieve data from /webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS: Server Error

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

```
vijay@ubuntu:~$ start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as vijay in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: namenode is running as process 22733.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-vijay-namenode.pid file is empty before retry.
Starting datanodes
localhost: datanode is running as process 22866.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-vijay-datanode.pid file is empty before retry.
Starting secondary namenodes [ubuntu]
ubuntu: secondarynamenode is running as process 23072.  Stop it first and ensure /tmp/hadoop-vijay-secondarynamenode.pid file is empty before retry.
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
vijay@ubuntu:~$ jps
23072 SecondaryNameNode
22866 DataNode
22733 NameNode
24447 Jps
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhdeu.png)

I am facing hadoop web console error
Currently installed java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18 and Hadoop 3.3.4

Comment: Well, did you enable WebHDFS? Why do you want to use it rather than `hdfs dfs -ls`?

Comment: Yes, I already enabled it into hdfs-site.xml still its show error

Comment: Did you look at the server logs?